# Categories for supervised classification, wildlife analysis

Tags: homework, ecology, gis

I am using GIS to undertake a small research on the loss of natural habitat in north England. I will be using Supervised Classification where I train the system on a few examples, e.g.

- shallow water
- deep water
- forest
- built area
  then based on a satellite image the software will create a map with these categories throughout.
  There is no detailed research question but I would like to have something a bit more detailed than just built environment, vegetation and water. On the other hand there is no need for tens of categories.

What categories should I use for this analysis and why?

Comment: Which research did you do on your own on this topic?

Comment: hi @daniel.neumann I'm only starting the research and the classification is the main bit of it so there are no results yet. I tired three categories but as I mentioned I think it's too broad. What do you recommend?